# 403 Forbidden error when trying to access Kubernetes API from a pod

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-apiserver

[As per this Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#accessing-the-api-from-a-pod), I am trying to access the Kuberenetes API from a pod, using the following command

`curl --cacert ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(<token)" https://kubernetes/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/ballerina-prime/scale`

which follows the following template

`curl --cacert ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(<token)" https://kubernetes/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/deployments/{name}/scale`

It throws the following error

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "deployments.extensions \"ballerina-prime\" is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:default:default\" cannot get resource \"deployments/scale\" in API group \"extensions\" in the namespace \"default\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "ballerina-prime",
    "group": "extensions",
    "kind": "deployments"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Can someone point out where I am making mistake or suggest any other way in which I can access the Kubernetes API?

**Update 01**

I created a Role as per the Documentation suggested. Following is the manifest I used.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: deployments-and-deployements-scale
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["deployments", "deployments/scale"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
```

I applied it using this command. `kubectl apply -f deployments-and-deployements-scale.yaml`. Still I am unable to access the endpoint needed. Where am I making mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you are connecting correctly to the kubernetes API!

But the default serviceaccount ("user") you are using does not have the required privileges to perform the operation, that you want to do. (Reading the deployment 'ballerina-prima' in the namespace 'default')

What you need to do: Use a different serviceaccount or grant the permissions that are required to the default service account.

You can find detailed information in the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/

Comment: I tried as mentioned in the Documentation. Still I am unable to access the endpoint. I have updated the question with what I tried. Can you have a look at it and make suggestions?

Comment: You need a RoleBinding in addition to assign the role to a subject (user).

Answer (score 7):

As @Thomas mentioned in the comment below his answer, you need to assign specific [Role](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) to the target Service [*account*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/) via [RoleBinding](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding) resource in order to fix this [*authorization*](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/) issue.

In reference to your manifest:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: deployments-and-deployements-scale
rules:
- apiGroups: ["extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["deployments", "deployments/scale"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: deployments-and-deployements-scale-rb
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: deployments-and-deployements-scale
  apiGroup: ""
```

You may consider either explicitly set `apiGroups:` in Role definition, matching particular [API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/kubernetes-api/#api-groups) groups or widely `["*"]` seeking through the all API versions.

Comment: In the `apiVersion` I am using `v1` whereas in the request `curl --cacert ca.crt -H "Authorization: Bearer $(<token)" https://kubernetes/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/default/deployments/ballerina-prime/scale` I am using `v1beta1`.  Do I need to make changes with respect to it?

Comment: It depends from what api group you've created deployment resource: if `extensions/v1beta1` then `.../apis/extensions/v1beta1/..` or `apps/v1` then `.../apis/apps/v1/...`